# Kotlin unresloved reference: serialization

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I need to use Kotlin serialization in a project.

For that purpose I am trying use:

```
import kotlinx.serialization
```

This is my project structure:

[image]

I have tried to follow what is written here https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization, and in several other answers around the internet but nothing has worked.

**I need the import only inside the server folder**.

Right now I have changed only the `build.gradle.kts` file that is in `server`, and this is how it looks:

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("jvm")// version "1.5.30"
    idea

    // val kotlinVersion = "1.4.31"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    // kotlin-spring is a wrapper on top of all-open - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html#spring-support
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.30" //  version kotlinVersion
    // kotlin-jpa is wrapped on top of no-arg - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/no-arg-plugin.html#jpa-support
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.5.30" // version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.6.10" // *ADDED FOR SERIALIZATION*
}

java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.2") //*ADDED FOR SERIALIZATION*

    // Protobuf Dependencies
    implementation(project(":stub"))
    // gRPC Dependencies
    api("io.grpc:grpc-netty:${rootProject.ext["grpcVersion"]}")
    api("io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${rootProject.ext["grpcVersion"]}")
    api("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:${rootProject.ext["protobufVersion"]}")
    api("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-kotlin:${rootProject.ext["protobufVersion"]}")
    api("io.grpc:grpc-kotlin-stub:${rootProject.ext["grpcKotlinVersion"]}")

    //     https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12
    // implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:${rootProject.ext["log4jVersion"]}")

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.zookeeper/zookeeper
    implementation("org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:${rootProject.ext["zookeeperVersion"]}")

    // https://github.com/MicroUtils/kotlin-logging
    //    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging-jvm:2.0.10")
    //    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-slf4j:1.5.2")

    // Coroutine dependencies
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:${rootProject.ext["coroutinesVersion"]}")

    // Spring (REST API) Dependencies
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    runtimeOnly("com.h2database:h2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}
```

This is the `build.gradle.kts` that is outside of the folders:

```
plugins {

    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.8.17" apply false
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.31" apply false
    id("org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint") version "10.2.0"
    idea
}



ext["grpcVersion"] = "1.39.0" // need to wait for grpc kotlin to move past this
ext["grpcKotlinVersion"] = "1.2.0" // CURRENT_GRPC_KOTLIN_VERSION
ext["protobufVersion"] = "3.18.1"
ext["coroutinesVersion"] = "1.5.2"
ext["zookeeperVersion"]  = "3.5.9"
ext["log4jVersion"] = "1.7.25"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    apply(plugin = "org.jlleitschuh.gradle.ktlint")
    apply(plugin = "idea")

}

tasks.create("assemble").dependsOn(":server:installDist")
```

I have marked with `//*ADDED FOR SERIALIZATION*` the code I added, but this doesn't work. Is there something else I am supposed to change or something that I haven't changed properly?

Comment: Do you really need Kotlin serialization? Or can be any serializer such as Gson and Jackson

Comment: Your kotlin serialization version is different from your kotlin version. Try changing the serialization version to 1.5.31

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who faces this in the future - going to File -> Invalidate Cache/ Restart solved the problem.